# How can set the horizontal gridlines based on the right y-axis with matplotlib?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

We can set the grid based on the right y-axis with matlab:
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/671503-how-to-set-the-grid-of-the-right-yyaxis

[image]

You see that the horizontal gridlines based on the right y-axis ,instead of the left y-axis.In matplotlib,`ax.grid(axis = "y")` draw the horizontal gridlines based on the left y-axis.

```
ax.grid(axis = "y")
```

How can do it with matplotlib then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have two y-axis, you can set the secondary axis grid to true using `ax2.grid()`. Working example...

```
fig, ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(7,7))
ax1=ax.twinx()
ax1.set_ylim(-1,3)
ax1.grid()
ax.xaxis.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

[image]